# How to plot different functions in a continuous manner?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a graph which has three different sections. Though I have managed to plot the first two sections in a continuous manner, I could not get the orientation of the third one correctly. The plot is of distance covered during accelerated, constant and decelerated motions. Ideally the last part of the graph (decelerated motion) should start at t = 7 and end at t = 11, in a smooth continuous manner, i.e. pointing upwards. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better/simpler way to plot all three?

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}          

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,compat=1.17} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline,trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,ylabel={Distance (m)},xlabel={Time (sec)},grid=major]
\addplot [red,mark=*,only marks] coordinates {
(0,0)
(11,540)
};
\addplot [red,mark=*] coordinates {
(6,270)
(7,360)
};
% speed is constant between 6 and 7, a =0
\addplot [domain=0:6,red]{7.5*x*x} ;
% s =  at^{2}/2; a = 15 m/s^{2}
\addplot [domain=7:11, red]{(90*x+(-11.25*x*x)+360} ;
% s = s_{0} + v_{0}t + at^{2}/2; a = -22.5 m/s^{2}, v = 90m/s
% added 360 so that it starts from where it left, initial value

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to de-phase the time 7 seconds in the third section. So changing `x` for `x-7` will result in the following.

As you can note I added the `siunitx` (v2020)  package to manage the units in the axes.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}  % SI units
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,compat=1.17} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline,trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,ylabel={Distance (\si{\meter})},xlabel={Time (\si{\second})},grid=major]
\addplot [red,mark=*,only marks] coordinates {(0,0)
(11,540)
};
\addplot [red,mark=*] coordinates {
(6,270)
(7,360)
};
% speed is constant between 6 and 7, a =0
\addplot [domain=0:6,red]{7.5*x*x} ;
% s =  at^{2}/2; a = 15 m/s^{2}
\addplot [domain=7:11, red]{(90*(x-7)-11.25*(x-7)*(x-7)+360)} ; % changed x for x-7
% s = s_{0} + v_{0}t + at^{2}/2; a = -22.5 m/s^{2}, v = 90m/s
% added 360 so that it starts from where it left, initial value

% if you plot the fist 4 seconds of the original function (uncomment the following):
%\addplot [blue, domain=0:4]{(90*x)-11.25*x*x+360)} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to see it more clearly, just uncomment the last line in my code that plots (in blue) the first 4 seconds of the third section of the plot. This is you original code, changing only the domain. You'll get this:

[image]

Comment: Well observed about the required shift :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, don't get your point. If I check the two formulas you gave:

```
{7.5*x*x} ;
{(90*x+(-11.25*x*x)+360} ;
```

then data are as you plot:
[image: checking data produced by the two formulas]

If you want something like the blue sketch, you need to check your formulas, i.e. the second one.

[image: guess about intention]

Physically spoken I have no idea how you came up with the second formula. It may be correct, if you'd specify the circumstances. But probably you intended sth. different.